# In mvvm the view doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i am beginner in mvvm concept.so i tried one sample application.it contains two textbox are name and id, one submit button,one label.when i click submit button it combine the two strings from the textbox and display in label.

i can submit the values and in viewmodel the property contain the result.but its not shown in view.why..?

in view contains

```
<grid>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding name}"  Height="23"  Margin="9" Name="txtname"  Width="120" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding id}" Height="23"  Margin="9" Name="txtid"  Width="120" />
<Button Command="{Binding submit}" Content="submit" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="23"   Name="btnsubmit"  Width="75" />
<Label Content="{Binding display}" Grid.Row="3" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="lbldisplay"  Width="192" />

</grid>
```

view.cs code is

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new DemoViewModel();
    }
```

in my viewmodel contains two .cs file

one is DemoViewModelInotify.cs.in this i write the code for inotifypropertychanged.
another one is DemoViewModel.cs.this contain the property and commands.

```
namespace mvvmdemonixon.ViewModel
{
public  class DemoViewModel :DemoViewModelInotify
{
  public ICommand submit { get; set; }

  public string name { get; set; }
  public string display { get; set; }
  public int id{get;set;}
  public DemoModel model { get; set; }
  public DemoViewModel()
  {

      submit = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.add);

  }

  public void add(object paramter)
  {
    string a=  mvvmdemonixon.Model.DemoModel.addstring(name, id);
    display = a;
  }

}
}
```

my model contains

```
namespace mvvmdemonixon.Model
{
public  class DemoModel
{
   public static string addstring(string name1, int no1)
   {
       string display = "The Student Name Is " + name1 + "and Id Is" + no1 + ".";
       return display;
   }

}
}
```

in my app.xaml.cs

```
private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        mvvmdemonixon.MainWindow view = new MainWindow();
        view.DataContext = new mvvmdemonixon.ViewModel.DemoViewModel();
        view.Show();
    }
```

in my app xaml

```
<Application x:Class="mvvmdemonixon.App"
Startup="OnStartup">
</Application>
```

advance thanks..

Answer (score 2):

WPF binding engine uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` (for scalar properties) and `INotifyCollectionChanged` (for collection properties) interfaces to reflect changes, which has been made in bound data source (view model).

This:

```
public string display { get; set; }
```

means, that any property setting will *not* notify the view, because setter's code doesn't contain any notifications. The code should be like this:

```
public string display 
{ 
    get { return _display; }
    set
    {
        if (_display != value)
        {
            _display = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("display");
        }
    } 
}
private string _display;
```

where `OnPropertyChanged` raises `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.

This is true for other view-bound properties in your view model, which should update the view.

Comment: hi @dennis i added inotifypropertychanged and make the property like above.it hit the onpropertychanged but its not updating in view..why..?

Comment: @nixen09: please, show updated code. Also, what is `DemoViewModelInotify`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your ViewModel.
And raise the property changed event from each property setter.

Comment: hi @michaels i added inotifypropertychanged and make the property like above.it hit the onpropertychanged but its not updating in view..why..?

Comment: @nixen09: Make sure you use two way binding - '{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}'

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you were missing. The first thing is your View's binding is OneTime. The second thing is you ViewModel does not notify when a property changed.

To fix the first problem, you have to update xaml like below.

```
<Label Content="{Binding display, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="3" Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="lbldisplay"  Width="192" />
```

To fix your second problem, you have to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Comment: > first thing is your View's binding is OneTime: by default, binding mode here will be two way.

Comment: @Dennis That's incorrect. Binding Mode default value depends on control type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx

Comment: You're partially right, I've missed, that bound control is `Label`. So, default mode will be `OneWay`, not `OneTime`. There's still no need to set `OneWay` explicitly.